# xcodebuild permissions failure

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am building an iOS framework that contains multiple projects in a workspace with an `xcodebuild` command that has always worked and has not changed. I do not know what caused this error to start happening but this is the output I get for pretty much every module of the workspace (names of modules are changed for the sake of confidentiality):

```
2016-05-05 15:20:27.368 xcodebuild[8728:391661]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-10150/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/BuildSystem/DependencyGraph/XCDependencyGraph.mm:688
Details:  unable to write dependency graph: You don’t have permission to save the file “Module1.build” in the folder “Release-iphoneos”.
Object:   <XCDependencyGraph>
Method:   +loadOrCreateInBuildDirectory:withTargetBuildContext:withBasePath:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8ea072b2b0>{number = 11, name = (null)}
```

At the end of the log, I also see this:

```
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2016-05-05 15:20:27.440 xcodebuild[8728:391665] Unable to create containing folder at '/Users/david/Dev/project/platform/ios/build/Build/Intermediates' for the shared cache directory.
2016-05-05 15:20:27.440 xcodebuild[8728:391665] Unable to create the shared cache directory at '/Users/david/Dev/project/platform/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders' with read/write permissions only for the currently logged in user.
2016-05-05 15:20:27.531 xcodebuild[8728:391658] Error saving log: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/david/Dev/project/platform/ios/build/Logs/Build/266D7DA5-68DD-449D-BA0A-FD0223CA1094.xcactivitylog, NSLocalizedDescription=No such file or directory} | User info: {
NSFilePath = "/Users/david/Dev/project/platform/ios/build/Logs/Build/266D7DA5-68DD-449D-BA0A-FD0223CA1094.xcactivitylog";
NSLocalizedDescription = "No such file or directory";
}
** CLEAN FAILED **

** BUILD FAILED **

2016-05-05 15:20:27.570 xcodebuild[8728:391658] Error saving log: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/david/Dev/project/platform/ios/build/Logs/Build/4D7E0CB2-5C94-4219-A666-0FB85DF2F158.xcactivitylog, NSLocalizedDescription=No such file or directory} | User info: {
NSFilePath = "/Users/david/Dev/project/platform/ios/build/Logs/Build/4D7E0CB2-5C94-4219-A666-0FB85DF2F158.xcactivitylog";
NSLocalizedDescription = "No such file or directory";
}
```

The command I am using is this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme Framework -configuration Release clean build -derivedDataPath /Users/david/Dev/project/platform/ios/build | xcpretty
```

Running `xcodebuild -version` yields this:

```
Xcode 7.3.1 
Build version 7D1014
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Do those files/directories already exist?  If so what is their ownership/permissions?

Comment: @trojanfoe they are generated when the command starts. I should be able to delete the `build` folder, run this command, and everything is generated for me. Permissions were never an issue before.

Comment: There is no need to be rude. Here are some potentially notable things that have changed.

- I have also recently updated to OS X 10.11.4. 
- I was previously using alcatraz for some third party plugins in Xcode - i've deleted the tool and all it's derived data
- I went and manually cleaned the derived data folder for xcode. I am able to build the project myself in xcode. How can i check permissions on a folder that is generated by xcodebuild, and then deleted when the build fails?

Comment: I was rude?  I asked you if the files existed and if so what permissions they were and you want to talk about how things were before. You have yet to tell us if the permissions of existing files are an issue.

Comment: I do not think there are issues with permissions of existing files in the folder I run the command - read & write for everything. The problem is seeing this `You don’t have permission to save the file “Module1.build” in the folder “Release-iphoneos”.` but not being able to check that folder's permissions because it is deleted after xcodebuild fails.